# Support for Office 365 Videos via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

How to access Office 365 Videos via Microsoft Graph API? What would be the endpoint for the same?

As per the documentation on Office 365 Discovery service, it clearly says to use Microsoft Graph for all accessing all Office 365 resources, but it doesn't give any end point or any information for Videos.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/discovery-service-rest-operations#DiscSvc_Token

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

For what I understood Office 365 Videos is going to be replaced by Microsoft Stream and I guess they don't plan to migrate Office 365 Videos API in Microsoft Graph as they will probably directly implement API for Microsoft Stream in Microsoft Graph.

But in the meantime I am like you, I don't know how we can continue to query the Office 365 Videos API as it is deprecated.